# How to reproduce this crash "not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode"

Tags: android, crash, android-sqlite

i am storing the details entered by user to SD Card using sqlite db.

the below crash was happening when i access to db. i want to reproduce this crash. can any help me to reproduce this crash.

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(SQLiteConnection.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
```

Comment: have you given read permission in manifest?

Comment: yes @VivekMishra

Comment: if i remove read permission, it can be reproducible? or any other method to reproduce this crash @VivekMishra

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513896/android-could-not-open-sql-database-error

Comment: i have removed the read permission and write permission persist. but i cant able to reproduce this crash...

Comment: From your crash logs it seems like lock condition. It is a guess but it is like your accessing database with 2 different instances

Comment: No, Its a single instance @VivekMishra